# CocoaPods not Installing properly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

my project was working fine until I installed the pushNotifications pod. It gave me an error that it is compatible with only ios 10.0 so I forced my pods version from global 9.0 to 10.0. After that I am unable to get my app to work. I have tried clean pods and reinstalling. I even tried by cleaning pod cache.
[image: Error]

I don't know how to explain this error. So, any help will be appreciated. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like 'pushNotifications' pod needs iOS 10+ to run and I think your project supports lower versions of iOS(i.e iOS 9). Because a pod global version specifies a minimum version to your pod to run which means, in your case, that the pods you add must support iOS 10+ otherwise your cocoapods won't be able to compile. And looks like you're using some pod that doesn't support iOS 10+(i.e AppAuth) that's why you're having this issue. 
I don't know which framework you're using but I really recommend you to take a look on it and find which one doesn't support iOS 10+ replace or update it because they need to support iOS 10+ otherwise it will be a huge problem for you in the future.

Comment: You are probably right. I overtook this project recently. And i was worried because the deployment target of our app was 9.0 and now I have an almost complete app using these pods and it will be a huge pain to extract it from a working project.

Comment: Btw I am not looking to use pushNotifications pod anymore. Is there any way to install 9.0 supporting pods forcefully. I have tried forced installing 9.0 but it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe is not possible to do it, at least I've never heard about it.
If the framework doesn't support the minimum iOS version specified in your project it won't run. The only way to make it works is making the changes necessary in your framework in order to support the minimum version you're using.

Comment: ricardo it is possible. I just had to go to backup and look for the version of pods that supported ios 9.0. eg google signin 4.8.0 works with iOS 9.0 but Google Signin 5.2.0 does not work with iOS 9.0. So, I just specified in my pod file to install Google SignIn version 4.8.0 and voila...